# Калькулятор на php c файлами

Tags: php, php7

Помогите с задачкой пожалуйста: Надо написать php скрипт, принимающий через консоль 2 аргумента (имя txt файла, тип операции) и записать ответ на другом txt файле. В txt файле на каждой строке записаны по 2 числа. Количество строк не ограничено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$argv - Массив переданных скрипту аргументов.
1 аргумент($argv[0]) всегда имя файла который запустили. $argv[1] у тебя будет имя файла $argv[2] будет тип операции. более подробно можно почитать тут
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Раз взялась отвечать то пиши как считывать из файла, как складывать, как записывать в файл.

Comment: если ты не умеешь элементарно проводить математические операции то будь добр посмотри это https://youtu.be/D6qyI8kHUkw?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXm69bqj5JTCS1XGTNkhTch если ты не можешь записать файл вот это самый простой пример https://youtu.be/Dy4XlMDo1WU?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXm69bqj5JTCS1XGTNkhTch